# Token gets expired and keeps going to IDP every a few seconds

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Is there a way I can force it to use cookie or modify the timeout span. It keeps going to the IDP every a few clicks or if the session was ideal for less than 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Core relaying party sample applications ASP.NET Core authentication and thereby actually cookies, where the tokens timeout is transferred to being the authentication / cookie lifetime.

If the problem is caused by short living tokens you can set the authentication / cookie lifetime in the `saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession` method in the `AuthController.AssertionConsumerService`.

In a ASP.NET Core application like this:

```
await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal), lifetime: new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Please rate the answer if you think the response was helpful and can be helpful for others, thanks.